# How to filter for a specific time period, which must be complete (have all months)?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, subset

I have a large data set, with repeated Plot measurements (count data) covering a large time span in different research areas. I now like to filter the data so that I only have complete field seasons left (April-November). Some areas are sampled in the same years, others in different years.

So far I have:

```
arthropods.all.sea <- with(arthropods.all, arthropods.all[month(Date) >= 4 & month(Date) < 12, ])
```

but can't figure out, how to include the condition that field seasons must be complete for each area.

Any help is very much appreciated.

I created a dummy data set, to illustrate how my real data set looks like.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("Ki_1","Ki_2","Ki_2","Ki_3","Ho_1","Ho_2"),
                  Date = as.POSIXct(c('1999-06-23', '1998-09-25', '1998-08-22', '2000-08-22', '1990-05-01', '1991-07-06')),
                  Area = c("Kin", "Kin", "Kin", "Kin","Hohe", "Hohe"),
                  Species=c("Species1","Species1","Species2","Species1","Species10","Species11"),
                  Count=c(12,23,21,14,7,2))
```

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible output using dput()

Comment: I just updated my question to include a dummy data set.

Comment: do you know which areas are sample in same year from April to Nov and which areas are sampled in different years?

Comment: Yes, I do know which areas are sampled in which year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select only those `Area` where all the months from April-November are present in the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

result <- df1 %>%
            mutate(year = year(Date), month = month(Date)) %>%
            group_by(Area, year) %>%
            filter(all(4:11 %in% month) & month %in% 4:11)
```

Comment: The code runs, but the output data.frame is exactly the same as the original one?

Comment: No, a few areas have data only for May in some years for example. I wonder if the year should be includet somewhere? As there maybe data for June for an area in one year but not for other years sampled...Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I want only the years for each area included there the data is complete for the months 4:12. The code seemed to have work, as it changes the data set - but somehow the data set is still not limited to months 4:12, all the other months are still there? Not sure whats going on here...It's subsetting something, but it's not doing what I'm looking for...

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion and many thanks! Can you please explain why you need the 4:12 %in% twice? So that I know for the next time?

Comment: `all(4:11 %in% month)` ensures that all the months from 4-11 are present in each `Group` and `each` `Year` which also mean that there could be data for month 1-3 along with 4-11 to remove those additional 1-3 months of data we use another `month %in% 4:11`.